# How to properly define virtual components for Vuetify 3 with Nuxt 3 and avoid 'Unexpected token' error?

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js, nuxtjs3, vuetifyjs3

I'm trying to define [virtual components for Vuetify 3](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/global-configuration/#using-with-virtual-components) with Nuxt 3.

When I follow the Vuetify's example (link above), I get the error below. How can I overcome this?

```
ERROR  Unexpected token '.'                                                                                        12:35:47 PM

  .v-btn {
  ^
  
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
  at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
  at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1124:15)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1160:27)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1250:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1074:32)                                                         12:35:45 PM
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:909:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1098:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:18)
  at jiti (node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:243592)
  at node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VBtn/VBtn.mjs:3:1
```

---

I belive it's caused by the fact that the `VBtn` definition is trying to import `.css` file.

First few lines of `VBtn.mjs`:

```
// node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VBtn/VBtn.mjs
import { withDirectives as _withDirectives, resolveDirective as _resolveDirective, createVNode as _createVNode } from "vue";
// Styles
import "./VBtn.css";
...
```

My `nuxt.config.ts`:

```
import { VBtn } from 'vuetify/components/VBtn';

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  typescript: {
    includeWorkspace: true,
  },
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
    '@invictus.codes/nuxt-vuetify',
  ],
  vuetify: {
    vuetifyOptions: {
      aliases: {
        VBtnPrimary: VBtn,
      },
      defaults: {
        VBtnPrimary: {
          class: 'cta px-12',
          variant: 'flat',
          size: 'x-large',
          rounded: '0',
        },
      },
    },
    moduleOptions: {
      treeshaking: true,
      useIconCDN: true,
      styles: 'sass',
      autoImport: true,
    },
  },
};
```

Dependencies:

- "@invictus.codes/nuxt-vuetify": "^0.2.20"
- "nuxt": "^3.4.3",
- "vuetify": "^3.3.1"

I tried replacing the VBtn with string `'VBtn'`, hoping that maybe Vuetify would search its own components based the string, but that didn't help.

Both Vuetify and Nuxt are working correctly, because when I tried to use string instead of component class, then on the preview page I got a warning that `Component is missing template or render function`. If Vuetify's `alias` option didn't work, I'd instead get an error from about an unrecognized component name.